# ruby-on-rails iterating through object attributes in view template aka .erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using ruby on rails.

wondering if this is achievable.

Original Code

```
<%= form_for(:page, :url=>{:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
<table summary="Subject Form Fields" %>
<tr>
 <th>Name</th>
 <td><%= f.text_field(:name) %></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <th>Position</th>
 <td><%= f.text_field(:position) %></td>
</tr>
<%end%>
```

desired code something along the lines of creating forms
by iterating through the object attributes.

```
  <% for attribute in @subject.attributes.keys %>
  <tr>
  <td><%= attribute.humanize %></td> 
  <td><%= @subject.attributes[attribute].to_s %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
```

so I am not sure if this is possible.

Comment: It looks entirely possible --- you can get the keys of any hash, and iterate over them, just like you're doing. Instead of a for-loop, in ruby you'll want to call .each to loop over an enumeration.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you are looking for is a .each loop:

```
<% @subject.attributes.each do |attribute| %>
<%= attribute.humanize %>
<% end %>
```

That will loop through each attribute of the @subject. If you also want to loop through the keys of each attribute, you need to add another nested loop:

```
<% @subject.attributes.each do |attribute| %>
  <% attribute.keys.each do |key| %>
    <%= attribute.humanize %> or <%= key %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Hope that helps.